# Realm with Alamofire and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm, alamofire

I am making my first attempt at using Realm in Swift. I have my model setup and I successfully receive the response using Alamofire and I map it to the object. I am then attempting to store the data in realm. It creates the object, but the values are the default values and not what is received from the backend. What am I missing?  Here's the model:

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper
import RealmSwift

@objcMembers class LoginResponseModel: Object, Mappable {

dynamic var status = ""
dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString
dynamic var userId = 0
dynamic var authToken = ""

required convenience init?(map: Map) {
    self.init()
}

convenience init(status: String, userId: Int, authToken: String) {
    self.init()
    self.status = status
    self.userId = userId
    self.authToken = authToken
}

override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    status <- map["status"]
    userId <- map["user_id"]
    authToken <- map["auth_token"]
}
}
```

Here is where I attempt to save it:

```
APIHelper.shared.login(username: username!, password: password!, success: { (result) in
            if let login = result {
                if (login.status != "failed") {
                    let userId = login.userId
                    let authToken = login.authToken
                    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(String(userId), forKey: "USERID")
                    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(authToken, forKey: "AUTHTOKEN")
                    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen



                    do {
                        let realm = try! Realm()
                        try realm.write {
                            realm.add(login)
                        }
                    } catch(let error) {
                        print(error)
                    }

                    InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
                        if let error = error {
                            print(error)
                        } else if let result = result {
                            self.sendToken(userId: String(userId), authToken: authToken, fcmToken: result.token)
                        }
                    }
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
```

Any ideas?

API call:

```
public func login(username: String, password: String, success: @escaping(_ response: LoginResponseModel?) -> Void, failure: @escaping(_ error: Error?) -> Void) {
    let url = "\(baseUrl)appLogin"

    AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: ["emailOrPhone": username, "password": password]).responseString { response in
        print(type(of: response).self)

        switch response.result {
        case .success(let json):
            let resp = LoginResponseModel(JSONString: json)
            success(resp)
        case .failure(let error):
            failure(error)
        }
    }
}
```

I get the object here:

```
let login = realm.objects(LoginResponseModel.self).first
```

Value of object:

```
status = ""
id = "1820A5D4-A714-4774-9707-4709ED39B570" 
userId = 0
authToken = ""
```

Comment: Hmm. What is `login` as it's not defined in the question. What does this mean *not what is received from the backend.*? Backend? Which backend and what data are you expecting?

Comment: Please share where you call the API attempt to map

Comment: @Jay login is the LoginResponseModel object. When I view the retrieved realm object it has the authToken = "" though I receive and successfully map the value from the API. And same for userId. But it does show the value for the UUID.

Comment: @dmorrow added the API call. The call works and successfully maps to the object. I originally was saving the data in UserDefaults, but decided to try storing in realm as a simple model for a first attempt.

Comment: The problem is the question has disjointed snippets of code that appear unrelated. For example, the write to realm could be happening before the object is populated so therefor the properties are their default values. Take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Update the question with a small example that duplicates the issue and we can take a look.

Comment: @Jay I believe I have added the rest of the necessary code

Comment: Per @Jay, its not clear the sequence of method calls - `login` and `APIHelper.shared.login` and when you're getting the object out of Realm

Comment: @dmorrow I apologize, I've been grinding at this all day and not thinking through. I call the method to get the object in the next view. I noticed that I was presenting the view before saving, and so I moved the present code to below where I write to realm. It is in the viewDidLoad method. Is there a completion block for writing to realm?

Comment: Much better question. Thanks. Right after this line `let resp = LoginResponseModel(JSONString: json)` add a `print(resp)` and see what it prints. Also, Realm writes don't have closures other than the closure you perform the write in but you could build one. What type of data are you wanting to see in the closure?

Comment: @Jay When I do the print I see the correct data mapped. I just want to be sure that the code doesn't move on until the write it complete, but I just read that the realm.write is synchronous, so I don't need to worry about that, right?

Comment: Correct. Is the object still not being populated correctly? If it's still not working, try examining the Realm file with Realm Studio to see if the data for that object is there.

Comment: Yeah, it's still not populating correctly. I don't have a realm file. Is that the problem?

Comment: In all the tutorials I have read through, not a single one has mentioned a realm file, or how to create one.

Comment: @linuxer How do you know that the value of the login object is as you show? Do not rely on the debugger output as the proxy object will show only your default values. You can try `print login.status` etc to view each individual field, or try stepping through code dependent on the field values.

Comment: Did you check the object in Realm Studio? I am not convinced that what you are seeing is actually what's happening as Realm object are lazily loaded and their current values may not be reflected in the debugger.

Comment: To answer your question: a realm (file) is created when it's written to. Look at the  [Realm Getting Started guide](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#realms). The first thing it shows is *To open a Realm, instantiate a new Realm object:* You have that code so you will have a realm file on your drive/device. Try moving that print statement you added earlier 'fuirther down' in the code to see where/when the object doesn't have correct values. btw, when responding to comments, precede the user name you're responding to with an at, like @Jay. That way we are notified of your response.

Comment: @ChrisShaw I am printing the library.status, and also tried setting it to a var and still shows "".

Comment: @Jay I will go through that guide again and hope I find the answer. Thanks

Comment: @ChrisShaw I finally tracked down where the .realm file is and it does show the data there. So it does work. And I must have been doing something off, because if I print(login.status) it shows in the log... so I guess it is working. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to print all `realm.objects(LoginResponseModel.self)`, not just the `.first`?

Comment: @dmorrow I have it all working now. Not sure what I was doing wrong yesterday, but I think it was working all along, just for one reason or another not showing in the debug view.